# Use regular expression to extract attribute value for custom tag

Tags: php, regex

Thanks for taking a look at this. I'm using PHP. I have a string like so:

```
[QUOTE="name: Max-Fischer, post: 486662533, member: 123"]I don't so much dance as rhythmically convulse.[/QUOTE]
```

And I want to pull out the values in the quotes and create an associative array like so:

```
["name" => "Max-Fischer", "post" => "486662533", "member" => "123"]
```

Then, I would like to remove the opening and closing [QUOTE] tags and replace them with custom HTML like so:

```
<blockquote><a href="URL_I_WILL_GENERATE_FROM_THE_ARRAY_VALUES">Max-Fischer</a> wrote: I don't so much dance as rhythmically convulse.</blockquote>
```

So the main problem is creating the preg_match() or preg_replace() to handle first: grabbing the values out in an array, and second: removing the tags and replacing them with my custom content. I can figure out how to use the array to create the custom HTML, I just can't figure how to use regular expressions well enough to achieve it.

I tried a match like this to get the attribute values:

```
/(\S+)=[\"\']?((?:.(?![\"\']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>\"\']))+.)[\"\']?/
```

But this only returns:

```
[QUOTE
```

And that's not even addressing how to put the values (if I can get them) into an array.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Cheers.

Comment: is the tag always going to be `[QUOTE ...]...[/QUOTE]`?

Comment: You already solved this for me, but yes, it will alway be [QUOTE] tags. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tag you're looking for is always going to be quote, then perhaps something a little simpler is possible:

```
  $s ='"[QUOTE="name: Max-Fischer, post: 486662533, member: 123"]I don\'t so much dance as rhythmically convulse.[/QUOTE]';

  $r = '/\[QUOTE="(.*?)"\](.*)\[\/QUOTE\]/';  

  $m = array();
  $arr = array();
  preg_match($r, $s, $m);
  // m[0] = the initial string
  // m[1] = the string of attributes
  // m[2] = the quote itself
  foreach(explode(',', $m[1]) as $valuepair) { // split the attributes on the comma
    preg_match('/\s*(.*): (.*)/', $valuepair, $mm);
    // mm[0] = the attribute pairing
    // mm[1] = the attribute name
    // mm[2] = the attribute value
    $arr[$mm[1]] = $mm[2];
  }
  print_r($arr);
  print $m[2] . "\n";
```

this gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Max-Fischer
    [post] => 486662533
    [member] => 123
)
I don't so much dance as rhythmically convulse.
```

If you want to handle the case where there is more than one quote in the string, we can do this by modifying the regex to be slightly less greedy, and then using `preg_match_all`, instead of `preg_match`

```
  $s ='[QUOTE="name: Max-Fischer, post: 486662533, member: 123"]I don\'t so much dance as rhythmically convulse.[/QUOTE]';
  $s .='[QUOTE="name: Some-Guy, post: 486562533, member: 1234"]Quidquid latine dictum sit, altum videtur[/QUOTE]';

  $r = '/\[QUOTE="(.*?)"\](.*?)\[\/QUOTE\]/';
  //                         ^  <--- added to make it less greedy
  $m = array();
  $arr = array();
  preg_match_all($r, $s, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  // m[0] = the first quote
  // m[1] = the second quote
  // m[0][0] = the initial string
  // m[0][1] = the string of attributes
  // m[0][2] = the quote itself
  // element for each quote found in the string
  foreach($m as $match) { // since there is more than quote, we loop and operate on them individually
    $quote = array();
    foreach(explode(',', $match[1]) as $valuepair) { // split the attributes on the comma
      preg_match('/\s*(.*): (.*)/', $valuepair, $mm);
      // mm[0] = the attribute pairing
      // mm[1] = the attribute name
      // mm[2] = the attribute value
      $quote[$mm[1]] = $mm[2];
    }
    $arr[] = $quote; // we now build a parent array, to hold each individual quote
  }
  print_r($arr);
```

This gives output like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Max-Fischer
            [post] => 486662533
            [member] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Some-Guy
            [post] => 486562533
            [member] => 1234
        )

)
```

Comment: Jeez pala_, are you a wizard? Thanks again for solving a tough problem for me. You're the best!

Comment: BTW, is there a way to tweak this so that it can handle multiple [QUOTE]'s in the same string?

Comment: @CalebJacobo sure there is. see amended answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve yout problem: to get **an associative array**. I hope it will help you.

Here is code

```
$str =  <<< PP
[QUOTE=" name : Max-Fischer,post : 486662533,member : 123 "]I don't so much dance as rhythmically convulse.[/QUOTE]
PP;

preg_match_all('/^\[QUOTE=\"(.*?)\"\](?:.*?)]$/', $str, $matches);
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+:\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $matches[1][0], $result);

$your_data = array_combine($result[1],$result[2]);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Almas, you and pala_ really helped me out.